# How to remove extra space after volume number in References section

Tags: bibliographies, spacing, apa-style

When I compile my manuscript, in the references section extra space is added after the volume number. My corrector told me to remove it, but the problem I don't know how to remove it.

**MANUSCRIPT.TEX**

```
\documentclass[man]{apa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}

\makeatletter  
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}  
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}  
\makeatother 

\title{...}
\author{...}
\affiliation{...}

\abstract{...}
\acknowledgements{...}  

\shorttitle{...}
\rightheader{...}
\leftheader{...}

\begin{document}  
\maketitle    

\section{...}    

\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

**References.bib**

```
@ARTICLE{BergCollier1953,
   author  = {Berg, I. A. and Collier, J. S.},
   year    = {1953},
   title   = {Personality and Group Differences in Extreme Response Sets},
   journal = {Educational Psychological Measurement},
   volume  = {13},
   pages   = {164--169}
}

@ARTICLE{BergCollier1953,
   author  = {Berg, I. A. and Collier, J. S.},
   year    = {1953},
   title   = {Personality and Group Differences in Extreme Response Sets},
   journal = {Educational Psychological Measurement},
   volume  = {13},
   number  = {X},
   pages   = {164--169}
}
```

OUTPUT

> Berg, I. A., & Collier, J. S. (1953).
>   Personality and group diﬀerences in
>   extreme response sets. *Educational
>   Psychological Measurement*, *13*   ,
>   164–169.
>
> Berg, I. A., & Collier, J. S. (1953).
>   Personality and group diﬀerences in
>   extreme response sets. *Educational
>   Psychological Measurement*, *13*
>   (X), 164–169.

The extra space is added on every reference (see the X after the volume number).

Normally where the **X** stands a volume number is entered, like this 10(3). When I enter this volume number the comma is place directly after the 10(3).

I really hope that someone can help me!

I figured out that I must change apacite.bst. However, I need to find the exact solution.

**PART OF APACITE.BST**

```
% format journal, volume, number and pages  
% call with  
%   formatted.pages format.journal.vol.num.pages.check  
%  
FUNCTION { format.journal.vol.num.pages.check }  
{ "journal" journal warning.if.empty  
 duplicate$ empty$  
journal    empty$ and  
volume     empty$ and  
  { pop$ "" }  
{ "\APACjournalVolNumPages{" journal "" connect.check  
  "}{" *                     volume  "" connect.check  
  "}{" *                     number  "" connect.check  
  "}{" *                     swap$   "" connect.check  
  "}"  *  
}  
if$  
}
```

Comment: @Patrick: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: @Patrick Could you please post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? If I compile a document with this preamble, no extra space is added after the volume number.

Comment: @Patrick: What `\bibliographystyle` and what special bibliography packages, if any (e.g. `natbib`) do you use? A compilable example would be even be better.

Comment: @lockstep By default, apa.cls uses the apacite package by Erik Meijer for citations which offers complete coverage and excellent conformance to APA guidelines, including apacite handling of electronic sources and non-English language forms. You should count on using bibTeX with the corresponding apacite.bst style file for your bibliography.

Comment: Maybe I can make some changes to apacite.bst?

Comment: I see that it works now I only have to figure out how to edit this part. See my post above!

Comment: @Patrick: You should *not* have to modify the bst file. If you read dibonas's comment he said that things work as expected with no change. (For me too.) So you need to do the same thing.  Start with a document that is *just* `\documentclass[man]{apa}\begin{document}\cite{yourKey}\bibliography{yourBibfile}\end{document}` and see if that produces the extra space (it shouldn't).  If it doesn't then you need to start adding/removing other packages to the preamble of this document until the problem reapears, and replace your sample document with  that document to your answer.

Comment: @Alan Munn: I just did what you said. I made a document with just `\documentclass[man]{apa}\begin{document}\cite{yourKey}\bibliography{yourBibfile­}\end{document}`. However, the extra space is still present...

Comment: @Patrick.  Then things are not working as they are supposed to. The document I put in my comment produces no extra space with your bib file.  Is your MiKTeX up to date?

Comment: @Alan Munn: While updating I fixed the problem by replacing the new apacite.bst by an older version of apacite.bst. I simply downloaded it via Google. This is probably not the best solution, but it works for now :).  `%% apacite.bst : reference list according to APA manual %% Written by Erik Meijer <e.meijer@eco.rug.nl> %% This version: [2005/06/08]`

Comment: @Alan Munn @lockstep @diabonas: many thanks for your warm welcome, help and suggestions!

Comment: @Patrick: If you found a solution to your problem, please repost your comment as an answer. Self-answers are perfectly acceptable in such a case, and it will help to remove your question from the "Unanswered Questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

While updating I fixed the problem by replacing the new `apacite.bst` by an older version of `apacite.bst`. I simply downloaded it via Google. This is probably not the best solution, but it works for now :).

```
%% apacite.bst : reference list according to APA manual 
%% Written by Erik Meijer <e.meijer@eco.rug.nl> 
%% This version: [2005/06/08]
```

Comment: If you still had the older version, it would have been helpful to `diff` the two files, so we could see the difference.